# Any 5-cycle in $\mathbb{S}_5$ can be obtained from another 5-cycle

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

I'm trying to go through the proof that a subgroup of $\mathbb{S}_5$ with a 5-cycle and a transposition is the whole group found on [this link](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~miller/old/m542-00/galois.pdf). However, I'm not able to understand why we can assume that the 5-cycle is $(1,2,3,4,5)$. This is not the only reference where I saw it assumed, but I still don't see clearly why is this the case. How can I get that 5-cycle from any 5-cycle?

Comment: I mean, if all you really want is the assumption that the $5$-cycle is $(1,2,3,4,5)$, you can use the handy fact that mathematics does not depend on symbols used. :P  The link goes a bit further in that it assumes simultaneously that the $5$-cycle is $(1,2,3,4,5)$ and the transposition is $(1,i)$. Matt Samuel's answer shows a kind of autmorphism that should take care of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sigma(1,2,3,4,5)\sigma^{-1}=(\sigma(1),\sigma(2),\sigma(3),\sigma(4),\sigma(5))$$